# Insert image into Word document TextBox

Tags: c#, image, gembox-document

I'm using GemBox.Document to generate an output document from a template. I want to insert an image inside a TextBox which will have the same size as that TextBox.

[image: Word document with TextBox]

How can I do that?

```
DocumentModel document = DocumentModel.Load("mytemplate.dotx");
TextBox textBox = (TextBox)document.GetChildElements(true, ElementType.TextBox).First();
Picture picture = new Picture(document, "myimage.png");
textBox.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(document, picture));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
DocumentModel document = DocumentModel.Load("mytemplate.dotx");
TextBox textBox = (TextBox)document.GetChildElements(true, ElementType.TextBox).First();

// If needed you can adjust the TextBox element's inner margin to your requirement.
textBox.TextBoxFormat.InternalMargin = new Padding(0);

// If needed you can remove any existing content from TextBox element.
textBox.Blocks.Clear();

// Get TextBox element's size.
var textBoxSize = textBox.Layout.Size;

// Create and add Picture element.
textBox.Blocks.Add(
    new Paragraph(document,
        new Picture(document, "myimage.png", textBoxSize.Width, textBoxSize.Height)));
```

I hope this helps.